# Can QWebView load images from Qt resource files?

Tags: qt, resources, qwebview

I've bundled some HTML and PNGs in my Qt app's resources file (for the help system). Unfortunately I can't find a way for the HTML to display images. I've tried various combinations of the `QWebView`'s base URL, and different URLs for the `<img>` tag but none have worked so far.

To be clear, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
QString html = "<html><img href=':/resources/cat.png'/></html>";
myWebView->setHtml(html, ???);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You probably want to set the imgage's `src` instead of it's `href`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try your resource format as:

```
qrc:/resources/cat.png
```

instead of

```
:/resources/cat.png
```

we have .css files that use images in such a format within webview and it works fine

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for (and I must have tried everything except that, `qrc://`, `qrc:///`, `:/`, etc). Thanks!