# QWebView displaing page from resource - doesnt work - blank page

Tags: c++, qt

I want to display my html page which I added to my projects resources. But my page wont display - I only see a blank page, see code below:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWebView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(html);

    QWebView *myWebView = new QWebView;
    //myWebView->load(QUrl("http://google.pl")); // always works
    myWebView->load(QUrl(":/html/index")); // doesnt work at all :(
    //myWebView->load(QUrl("index.html")); // works only when I have index.html in my build-dir
    myWebView->show();

    return a.exec(); }
```

added

```
QT += webkit
QT += webkit webkitwidgets
```

to *.pro file.

Heres my whole project: http://www.speedyshare.com/bzg2M/qt-web-page-resources.tar.gz

Comment: Just stating the obvious, have you checked this page in a regular browser?

Comment: @Georg: yes, I did. It works well in every browser I have (Chromium, Firefox, Rekonq)...

Comment: how about changing to qrc:/html/index.html, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187296/can-qwebview-load-images-from-qt-resource-files