# Can QWebView load *.js from Qt resource files and run them?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qtwebkit, qtwebview

I have **qrc** file that looks like this:

```
 <qresource prefix="/web">
        <file alias="assets.js">../web/assets.js</file>
        <file alias="index.html">../web/index.html</file>
</qresource>
```

Inside **assets.js** Just adding function for allert popup:

```
    function myFunction() 
    {
        window.alert("Hello from assets.js");
    }
```

Inside **index.html** adding another javascript for alert popup, loading **assets.js** and adding 2 buttons. First one to call window popup from external javascript file (**assets.js**) and second to call the javascript that is embeded into **index.html** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
        function localFunction() 
        {
            window.alert('HTML loaded');
        }

    </script>

    <script src="assets.js"></script>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">External JS</button>
    <button onclick="localFunction()">Local JS</button>


  </body>
</html>
```

Now when I'm trying to load **index.html** in qtwebkit:

```
webView->load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/web/index.html")));
```

I can see that **index.html** has been loaded ok (I can see the 2 buttons )
When clicking on the button that should call the local (html embeded) javascript it works.
Clicking the second button does nothing.

It seems like the external **assets.js** is not loaded properly.
Any sugestions how I can get it working?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187296/can-qwebview-load-images-from-qt-resource-files) question may help.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript isn't evaluated from the html. Your JS file could not be found. The following has no effect:

```
<script src="assets.js"></script>
```

Try it explicitly:

```
const QString js = readFile("qrc:/web/assets.js"); // Load your javascript file
view->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(js);
```

Another solution, more efficient: Use the QRC System and set the baseUrl in setHtml to link all files correctly:

```
   const QString html = readFile(":/index.html");
   view->setHtml(html, QUrl("qrc:/"));
```